# People who repeatedly post nonsensical questions

Tags: discussion, specific-user

I've come across [a user by the name of "professor Jeff"](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127310/professor-jeff) repeatedly these days, and this person keeps posting questions with nonsensical titles and paragraphs talking about "flying disk and timing box" (such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669071/bruce-alberts-when-will-i-receive-my-salary)). I would post some other examples but I think they have already been deleted by the Math.SE moderators.

My question is: What is Math.SE doing about users like these who *repeatedly* make accounts with the same name just to talk gibberish like this? Do we ban specific IPs after the first several occurrences? Do we make a filter that search for specific texts (in this case, "flying disk and timing box") and prevent users from making posts with those words?

I'm not trying to sound cynical, and I'm sorry if I do. I just want to know how Math.SE is handling situations like these. Because clearly, users like "professor Jeff" are ruining everyone's time in this great website. Thanks in advance, and sorry if this post sounds so unprofessional... this is my first one here in the meta!

Comment: Professor Jeff has been killed, mission accomplished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we ban specific IPs after the first several occurrences?

Yes, automatically (based on the input from the community, i.e., downvotes, closevotes, deletions): [Quality blocks enabled for questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10717/).

> Do we make a filter that search for specific texts (in this case, "flying disk and timing box")

No, because that would be much too easy to work around, just by changing nonsensical phrases to other nonsensical phrases. But users can take advantage of peculiar phrases like these by searching for them: locate all similar posts by the individual and downvote/closevote/closeflag them with extreme prejudice.

> users like "professor Jeff" are ruining everyone's time in this great website

Not mine :) thanks to [tag filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) I never saw those questions until you pointed them out (thankfully, prof. Jeff does not use my favorite tags).